# Ruby: Applying filters to text files (conditional printing)

Tags: ruby, text, conditional-statements, filtering

I have a CSV that has three types of info:
userID,wordID,ct

(Basically, 14k different tweeps, a different line for each word they use, including a count for that word)

I would like to be able to filter this file just for userIDs that have at least 2000 different wordIDs.

I understand how to go through the file and count up wordIDs per userID, but I don't know how to combine this with "now put 'userID,wordID,ct' just for the userIDs that are really frequent."

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'm processing the file currently. I suspect there are more efficient ways to do this as the file itself is 19m lines--thoughts on efficiency are certainly appreciated.

```
filename = ARGV[0]

file = File.new(filename, "r")

entry = {}

file.each do |line|
        user, word, ct = line.chomp.split(",")
        entry[user] = entry[user].to_i + 1
end

file = File.new(filename, "r")

file.each do |line| 
line.strip!
        user, word, ct = line.chomp.split(",")
        if entry[user] >= 2000
                puts line   
        end
end
```